# How can i render in my html file(Backbone js)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

So i have 3 files: index.html, router.js and view.js.

In my index.html i have : div with class : page.

In my router.js i have:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes : {

        '': 'home'
    }

});

var userList = new UserList();

var router = new Router();

router.on('route:home' , function(){
    console.log(userList);
    userList.render();
});

Backbone.history.start();
```

In my view.js i have :

```
var UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '.page',
      render: function(){

      this.$el.html('Content should be here! Wtf?');
     }
 });
```

What I need to modify in view.js to have in my index  in div:page "Content should be here! wtf?"

i get stucked...P.S if router(code) and view(code) are in a script tag in html its working but in differnt files dosent do anything.

Comment: Is view.js included *before* router.js in your index.html file?

Comment: yes , but finaly i solved this i just had to add on top of "var userList = new UserList(); this - >  $(function () { });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved :

```
 $(function () { 
 var userList = new UserList();

 var router = new Router();

router.on('route:home' , function(){
console.log(userList);
userList.render();
});

Backbone.history.start();
});
```